# jQuery "world" animations

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a "world" you could say (virtual world) using jQuery and PHP. A bit how it works first to help you better understand my question:

1. User's character's positions are taken from a database, user is plotted accordingly (the position values are CSS values - left and top)
2. User is able to move about using the arrow keys on the keyboard, making their character move using jQuery animations. While this is happening  (on each arrow press) the user's position values are inserted into a database and updated.
3. In order to make this "global" (so users see each other) as you could say, the values need to be updated all at once for each user using AJAX

The above steps I have figured out. However, when another user's positions are moved (meaning they press an arrow key) the move animation doesn't show for another user looking at that user. If you were to go on and move your character, you would see your character move perfectly fine using jQuery animations. But if you were to look at your friend move, he would "teleport", meaning he would move from one position to another with no animations. I know that JavaScript is obviously only for each user to see, but is there any way I can get it to show all animations to all users? So when you move, your friend would see you move animatedly rather than just getting repositioned.

Thank you for your potential help.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. I would suggest using a long poll to poll the DB (via ajax) and update each new sprite using the `animate()` function.

Comment: Each user will need to poll the DB for ALL user positions. Then the animation will need to be done on each user's browser for each sprite. So you will get a response from the server that tells you the positions for all 50 (for example) users on the screen. All 50 of the sprites must be animated to their new locations.

Comment: it is for this exact reason that most types of servers that do multi-user setups will force a certain MAX users at a time. This is to 'limit' bandwidth to what they can handle as this could 'pound' your servers if you have 10k ppl on at one time...

Comment: One way or another, all 10K people will need to know the locations of the other users if their locations are to be displayed. This means a lot of back-and-forth between the browsers and the server(s). This is not something you can work around. The alternative to long-polling would be to use the HTML5 WebSocket (http://polavenki.blogspot.com/2011/01/html5-websocket-alternative-to-long.html) for such communications, but if I understand it correctly, these connections are left open, so that's 10K constantly-open connections.

Comment: you are correct. But most servers will only allow like 200-400 ppl connected at one time... not 10k.... the 10k was an example of NOT having a certain limit on the number of people. If you get over the 400 person count, as a client.. you need to select a different server. As the host, you need to provide a different server.

Comment: Correct - and many times each of those servers are connected to one another as well. I think we are saying the same thing. There is a lot of back-and-forth no matter how you break it down.

Answer (score 0):

*(sorry for the separate answer, this probably belongs as a comment on Dutchie's answer but I cannot "comment everywhere" yet)*

If you are not displaying every user on the screen simultaneously, you could have a query for only users within view of the current user -- for example each user would call an "animateNearbyUsers()" function that would use the position of the current user to find all users within N squares/pixels and animate only those. This should make the process less of a performance problem as user count increases.

Answer (score 0):

There are no perfect solutions because of the latency but there are "good enough" solutions depending on your definition of "good enough".

The easiest would be to set up an animation queue, using each server response as kinda keyframes.

So say you get position a, b, and c from 3 consecutive polls to the server, you start an animation from a to b, then you get position c and you enqueue an animation from b to c to happen after the character finishes the first animation from a to b.

This should be (relatively) simple, but has the cost of the UI lagging behind, because they only start moving to the next location after the server determines that it has already arrived, but that may be acceptable for you.

The harder way is to try to "guess" where the user is going to be based on the direction that they were moving the last time you checked.  This involves getting not only position but direction (and possibly speed) and you'll still get jumps when you guess wrong, which can be smoothed out with more work.  This is essentially what most big name games do and it gets tricky to do it right.